# Read a file and based on condition perform some write operation

Tags: printing, awk, count, skip

I am newbie to awk. An I searched all over to figure this out myself and failed. This was my last resort. Please help.

I have a file which is very big as follows;

```
*SET
     7
636322    635890    632043    632044
636323    636322    632044    632045
*SET
     8
636315    636323    632045    632046
*SET
     9
635890    635889    635992    635994
635994    635992    635991    635993
635995    635991    635992    635996
635996    635992    635889    635888
```

I'd like to make it look like this

```
1    636322    635890    632043    632044
1    636323    636322    632044    632045
2    636315    636323    632045    632046
3    635890    635889    635992    635994
3    635994    635992    635991    635993
3    635995    635991    635992    635996
3    635996    635992    635889    635888
```

Basically have a condition to look for the string 'SET' and skip a line add a count-id in the first column, print the rest of the line continue until it sees the next 'SET'. Go on till the end of file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens to the lines with `7`, `8`, and `9`?

Comment: Oh, please ignore the blank lines in my note. For some odd reason, when I tried deleting the blank line, the line with single digits started combining with the line with the string SET :-( In my file where I'd be manipulating this, there are no blank lines. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Learn how to do markup in SO. If you want to post literal text or code, mark it with the mouse and use the `{}` code tool.

Comment: Lines indented with 4 spaces are literal code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Barmar. I'm learning.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/SET/ { counter++ }
     NF == 4 {printf("%d\t%s\n", counter, $0); }'
```

Comment: Thanks so much Barmar. Will this skip a line after it finds /SET/?

Comment: It ignores all the lines other than the ones with `SET` and the ones with `NF == 4`.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in stages.

First, deal with incrementing the counter.  the pattern you are looking to match is "SET" so define a variable in the BEGIN block, and increment it when you find the pattern "SET"

```
BEGIN {
cntr=1
}

/SET/ {
   cntr++;
   echo cntr;
}
```

Next, look to match the other important lines in the input. Don't bother with the blank lines -  if they don't match any patterns you've defined, nothing will happen.

Your other lines match a pattern : "start of line" "number".

$0 is awk-speak for "the whole line matching the current pattern".

When you meet one of these lines, you want to output the cntr and $0.

Hope this is enough hints to get you there, while you learn a bit more about awk

Comment: Not sure how this should solve OPs problem.  What does `echo` do here?

Comment: Got it. Actuially, there are no blank lines in my file at all. I had to add them in my note here to prevent the two line getting combined for some off reason. I got what you suggested. How can I ignore the line which is immediately after /SET/. Thanks.

Comment: I think Barmar's answer covers it all. With awk, if a line is not matched by a pattern, nothing happens for it.